# Prove $(f\ast g)'=f\ast g'$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question on differentiation of the convolution. If $f,g$ and $g'$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then is it true that $(f\ast g)'=f\ast g'$? I tried to use the difference quotient and the dominated convergence theorem, but couldn't solve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Start from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation

Answer (score 1):

Do it formally first.  Then for a smooth function g. Then for g as stated. Then try justifying it by using Lebesgue's dominated convergence.